# Updating and creating a form in Rails (understanding some code)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently following a tutorial on rails and the instructor is explaining most things very well so far. Currently he is teaching us how to make our own forms to add to the database from scratch, however I am kind of confused on exactly what purpose `article_params` is doing in our code below, Here is the full code in the `articles_controller.rb` file which is handling our form

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    render plain: article[:id].inspect
    if @article.save
      flash[:notice] = "Article was sucessfully created"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update(article_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Article was sucessfully updated"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title,:description)
  end
end
```

I understand what we are doing for the most part, but when I have the update and create actions, what is the private method `article_params` doing here? The instructor says it is used for white listing and proceeds to say several things which I really can't understand. For example why do we have `if @article.update(article_params)`, but not `if @article.save(article_params)`? As you can see, I am pretty confused about this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you don't want to accept *every value* coming through the wire.

Whenever you're dealing with user input, you should be careful about whitelisting the required parameters.

The `article_params` makes sure that you only permit certain attributes required for `mass assignment`. Suppose, you have an `admin` field which is a boolean(which should not modified by any standard user) and if you do

```
User.create(params[:article])
```

without watching for the values the user is sending to the server, you might accidentally allow that user to be an admin. Looks like a weak example, but can happen if you're not careful.

In your code, the `article_params` method returns a hash which will only have keys `title` and `description` and filters the rest of key-value pairs.

To visualize what's actually received from a `form`, replace your `create` action with the following. Before that, remove `description` from the permitted parameters in the `article_params` method.

```
def create
  render text: params
end
```

Now, if you try to create a form, you can find the values received. You can also see the values in the server logs but this is the easiest way.

And then replace your `create method` with

```
def create
  render text: article_params
end
```

You can find that the former method will show `description` but the latter won't as it filters it.

From the documentation,

> Action Controller Parameters
>
> Allows you to choose which attributes should be whitelisted for mass updating and thus prevent accidentally exposing that which shouldn't be exposed. Provides two methods for this purpose: require and permit. The former is used to mark parameters as required. The latter is used to set the parameter as permitted and limit which attributes should be allowed for mass updating.

To understand the difference between `save` and `update`, read
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a specific reason it is private then?

Comment: @cresjoy  Its private cause you're never going to call it from any other classes. Meaning, its used internally in the class and is not to be consumed by the other classes. 

From the documentation, "Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters is just a good pattern since you'll be able to reuse the same permit list between create and update. Also, you can specialize this method with per-user checking of permissible attributes."

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I understand, but I recall in one of my .erb files I had a condition saying if @articles.errors.any? Then display the errors. What I am assuming then, is that this article_params handles it internally, and that my if statement is just displaying it on the screen

Comment: Add a validation to your model in article.rb (for eg: `validates :title, presence: true`). And then fire your rails console. Try to create an `article`record without a title(I'm using `title`. You can use whatever your model has.) with `a = Article.new`. Note that every value is nil. If you try to save the record with `a.save`, it will return `false`. Now, try `a.errors`. You should find the error object with the error messages. Also try `a.errors.full_messages` and `a.errors.any?` For more, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages

Comment: Does the syntax of rails kind of seem odd at first? I feel like I am just memorizing some of these steps kind of. Hopefully it gets clearer later

Comment: @cresjoy. No,its not. I think its more intuitive. In ruby,everything is an object. And to perform any operation, you call methods on it. Whats nice about ruby is that you don't need parentheses after calling the function. Maybe its weird, but its easy to understand and more readable. You'll understand its beauty soon.

Comment: I hope so too! Thanks